# Android NDK - Save "native objects" between native code calls

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Right now I have a native function which sort of does this:

```
Object o = new Object();
while (!o.done()) { o.compute(); }
return o.result();
```

This computing can take a while and I would want the UI in Android to be update with some kind of progress bar. So what I need is three different native functions, one for each step above. The problem I'm having is how to save the "native object" inbetween calls. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `static Object *o;` in your <package_name>_<activity_name>. cpp file. Have one method to instantiate `o`. One method to call `o->compute()` if it still has to. Remember to `delete o;` in another method when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Android NDK C code statics act like statics do in normal application programming. As long as the current process (app) is running, your data will be preserved. If you have a method that will do a lot of processing, call it from a Java thread to work in the background like this:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable()
  {
      public void run()
      {
      <call native method here>
      }
  }).start();
```